# Python official keyserver

Tags: python, public-key

I have just downloaded the Python 2.7.3 64-bit installer from the [Python download page](http://www.python.org/getit/) and I would like to verify the signatures. So I need to import the keys and my preferred method is to get them from a trusted key server.

The method suggested in the Python documentation is using `gpg` from the command line with

```
gpg --recv-keys EA5BBD71 6A45C816 ED9D77D5 7D9DC8D2 A4135B38 36580288
```

However, no key server is indicated and I cannot find any information (even on google) about a key server (`--keyserver` option) providing these keys. The command as it is does not work: it connects to the default server `keys.gnupg.net` and exits with errors

```
gpgkeys: key ... not found on keyserver
```

Does anybody know where I can find a keyserver providing the official Python gpg keys?

Comment: The command works for me. My setup contacts `wwwkeys.pgp.net`.

Comment: It looks like that specific server (keys.gnupg.net) is b0rken; when searching for the email addresses I do find the keys: http://keys.gnupg.net/pks/lookup?search=barry%40warsaw.us&fingerprint=on&op=index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific key server works for me, with or without a `0x` prefix:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 0xEA5BBD71 0x6A45C816 0xED9D77D5 0x7D9DC8D2 0xA4135B38 0x36580288
```

On most keyservers I tried, in fact, the keys are present; my setup uses `wwwkeys.pgp.net`:

```
gpg --keyserver wwwkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys EA5BBD71 6A45C816 ED9D77D5 7D9DC8D2 A4135B38 36580288
```

Alternatively you'd have to manually download the [7D9DC8D2 key (Martin von Löwis)](http://keys.gnupg.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x6AF053F07D9DC8D2), used for signing the Windows builds and import that manually:

```
curl -o 7D9DC8D2.txt "http://keys.gnupg.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x6AF053F07D9DC8D2"
gpg --import 7D9DC8D2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I keep getting this error, even on `wwwkeys.pgp.net`, even with the `0x` prefix. Maybe there is something wrong with my gpg installation. I am using `gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.13` on cygwin.

Comment: @Giorgio: I tested with 1.4.12 on Mac, so it could be that the cygwin environment is your problem. You could go to the web interface and download the keys manually (copy and paste).

Comment: @Giorgio: Another alternative added: download the pubkeys.txt file and import that.

Comment: @Giorgio: ah, further experimentation shows that the `0x` doesn't matter, and that the pubkeys.txt file does not contain the right key. Given you a recipe for the Windows signing key instead.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed that the `pubkeys.txt` contains the wrong keys (and I wonder if downloading that file is a good idea against man-in-the-middle attacks). The curl solution does not work either, nor does searching the key directly on the website. Maybe I have a proxy / firewall problem.

Comment: @Giorgio: Searching the key servers for the keys does require you to prefix the key with `0x`. If you cannot search them even with that, then you indeed have a firewall problem somewhere.